# Concatenating NSString inside of UITextView

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I'm some trouble adding strings together for a UITextView in my app.  The method I've been using is this

(header)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface calculatorViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextView *output;
}

-(IBAction)b1;

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *output;

@end
```

(main)

```
#import "calculatorViewController.h"

@implementation calculatorViewController

-(void)b1 {
    [output stringByAppendingString:@"hi"];
}
```

The problem I've been having with this method is when I use the button the app crashes.  The warning it gives me is    'UITextView' may not respond to '-stringByAppendingString:'
When I replace output with at string it works though and that confused me.

Any suggestions?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to treat an `UITextView` as if it was a `NSString` - that just doesn't work. You need to fix that property declaration and set the text for the text view correctly, e.g.:

```
output.text = [output.text stringByAppendingString:@"hi"];
```